# eBooks download website, page or post?

Tags: posts, pages, e-commerce

I am creating an eBooks download website. There will be around 5000 eBooks. Each page/post will have a download link to the pdf file of the eBook. My question is, should I create 5000 pages or 5000 posts for these eBooks?

Answer (score 1):

Pages are relatively more static. They don't change much. Posts on the other hand do change on a regular basis. Just like any store, it's best to use posts in this case.

You can also create a custom post type and call it "ebooks". It would be more appropriate, but posts can do fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create posts or custom posts instead of pages because you may be use pages type for creating various pages like about us, contact us, privacy etc.